# Sort the merged data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the query to combine the data from multiple sheets
[image]

However the data is getting auto sorted as per sheets, I want the data to be sorted as date.

**Case scenario**
Data from different sheets are called as it available in the sheets, for e.g. Sheet 1 is having data of 1st June and 5th June and Sheet2 is having data of 2nd June. Data which are shown as combined are in this order: 1st June--5th June--2nd June.

**Requirement**

I want the data which are being called using query gets sorted automatically as per the date available in Column 1.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: You have to use `order by` clause. Show some sample data for better understanding.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the image in the question, kindly check and suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A1:C;Sheet3!A1:C;Sheet4!A1:C},"select * where Col2 is not 
null order by Col1")
```

Or alternatively, if you would like to sort with the most recent date first:

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A1:C;Sheet3!A1:C;Sheet4!A1:C},"select * where Col2 is not 
null order by Col1 desc")
```

More information on `order by` can be found in Google's [Query Language Reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by).